# Vertical alignment in IE7

Tags: html, css, xhtml

I have used CSS to create a tableless layout. While this renders properly in IE8, FireFox and Chrome, it does not on IE7, which I expected. But I was wondering if there was any solution for `vertical-align: middle;`. This seems to be the core of my problem in IE7.

```
#main { 
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 500px;
    display: table;
   position: relative;
}

#main ul {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align:center;
}
#main ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #d0dad2;
    height: 170px;  
}

<div id = "main">
    <ul> 
        <li><img src="images/test.jpg" alt="staff" /></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what exactly is the problem you are experiencing with **vertical-align: middle**? Maybe even show online?

Comment: @MeLight, on vertical-align: middle; does not work. so i was just wondering if there was a way to make it work in a conditional style sheet?

Comment: Here's the OP's situation in action http://jsfiddle.net/FWqPD/

Comment: IE7 doesn't support display: table-cell. See http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html#t06

Comment: @Blaise Kal i know it does not, thats why i was wondering if there was a way to get around it in ie7

Comment: OK, sorry :) On this page I have images middle-aligned in the gallery: http://www.maartenkal.com/en/photos/atlantic-and-carribean. See the CSS source in http://static.maartenkal.com/src/css/global.css line 494 - 517.

Comment: Doesn't allow me to edit my post after 5 mins. Wanted to add: Most important part of the trick is to apply the same line-height as the total height for the container element. Line 509 of the CSS.

Comment: Sorry for spamming. Made a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/RrF43/

Comment: @Blaise Kal, thank you for your effor but i'm afraid your solution is not quite what i am looking for as line-height would result to each list-item separated by 500px. This should not be the case, ideally, i would like the solution to be separated by just 10px

Comment: That's possible: http://jsfiddle.net/rgZMR/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at this tutorial by Chris Coyier:
http://css-tricks.com/vertically-center-multi-lined-text/

Hope this helps.